# Add a page to a PDF using PGraphics in Processing

Tags: java, pdf, processing

I'm trying to write an off-screen graphics buffer to print a PDF file using Processing.

The problem is that I can't add a new page by pdf.nextPage() when using createGraphics() to create the pdf file. The compiler says that that method doesn't exists.

I took this example from the reference web:

```
import processing.pdf.*;

PGraphics pdf = createGraphics(300, 300, PDF, "output.pdf");
pdf.beginDraw();
pdf.background(128, 0, 0);
pdf.line(50, 50, 250, 250);
pdf.dispose();
pdf.endDraw();
```

So, how can I add a page to the pdf file using PGraphics?

Thanks.

Comment: [PDF \\ Libraries \\ Processing\.org](https://processing.org:8443/reference/libraries/pdf/index.html) why don't you refer this example? -> Multiple Pages (No Screen Display)

Answer (score 2):

Simply cast to `PGraphicsPDF` and `nextPage()` will be available:

```
import processing.pdf.*;
//cast to PGraphicsPDF instead of PGraphics
PGraphicsPDF pdf = (PGraphicsPDF)createGraphics(300, 300, PDF, "output.pdf");
pdf.beginDraw();
//draw page 1
pdf.background(128, 0, 0);
pdf.line(50, 50, 250, 250);
//add page
pdf.nextPage();
//draw page 2
pdf.background(0, 128, 0);
pdf.line(50, 250, 250, 50);

pdf.dispose();
pdf.endDraw();
```